# How to get a particular values on priority basis

Tags: sql, rank

My table is as follows.

Table Values

```
ID      Values
----  ------
A1   ----  3
A2   ----  3
A3   ----  3
A4   ----  3
A5   ----  5
A6   ----  6
A7   ----  6
```

Table Priority

```
ID ------ Priority
A3 ----- 1
A2 ----- 2
A1 ----- 3
A5 ----- 4
A6 ----- 5
A4 ----- 6
A7 ----- 7
```

I want to find the lowest 2 value ID based on the priority for values less than 5.
If one or more ID has the same values then use the priority in the priority table and get the top 2 values from them.
As for the above case A1, A2, A3, and A4 has the same values and is less than 5. Then it should follow the priority given in priority table and fetches the top 2 records. For the above case it should show

```
ID ---- Values
A3 ---- 3
A2 ---- 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 2 tv.ID, tv.Values 
FROM table_values tv
INNER JOIN table_priorities tp
ON tv.Id = ip.ID
WHERE tv.values < 5
ORDER BY tv.values, tp.priority
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining the tables together, filtering the first table for the criterion on `value`.  Then order the results and choose the first two:

```
select v.*
from values v join
     priority p
     on v.id = p.id
where v.value < 5
order by priority
limit 2;
```

Different database engines have different ways of limiting the results to `2`.  So, the `limit` clause might be something else, such as `select top 2` depending on the database.